# How to show a message of specific page?

Tags: php, pagination

If I have a code to display the links of Page. and I want to show a message "You are in this page" what should I do? my code to display links of pages is

```
if( $page > 1 ) {
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page-1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Previous</a>';
}
for( $i = 1; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
if( $page < $totalPages ) {
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page+1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Next</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
echo "You are in $_REQUEST['page'] page";
```

and if you assign a current page into `$page` then use this,

```
echo "You are in $page page";
```

Answer (score 0):

On the landing page, you can check for `$_GET['page']`:

```
switch ($_GET['page']) {

  case 2: 
    'Do Something for page 2';
     break;

  case 3: 
    'Do Something for page 3';
     break;

  case 4: 
    'Do Something for page 4';
     break;
}
```